# Serializing from Object to XML String (complex types & lists)

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

Good Day Good Denizens of Stack Overflow,

Noob programmer here with another silly question. Having issues finishing a very big project I inherited from someone who left without notice. The application is a Web Crawler that tracks international ocean shipments and then feeds the resulting tracking events into a Logistics system (Magaya Cargo System) via a soap service API.

The event data is a node within the shipment XML file itself and the Magaya API has a special method that I can use for inserting these events. Basically the method `SetTransactionEvents` allows me to specify a shipment number and pass it an XML string of the events that pertain to that shipment. My issue is when I attempt to Serialize my events into the XML string I am not able to form an XML in the right structure that the method is expecting causing a crash. I have tried several different approaches to this, but I struggle a bit understanding the complex types which these events use.

Here is my code, first the one that calls my serialization method. To keep it brief I omit the part that sets the values from the webcrawler tracking results. Nothing major, just a bunch of `webeventDate = classeventDate`...etc. :

```cs
EventType cur_event = new EventType();
EventDefinitionType eventDefinition = new EventDefinitionType();
// All Fields of the cur_event object are set here...
InsertEventIntoMagaya(cur_event);
```

See below code snippet showing the serializing part of my code, some dummy variables in for now:

```cs
public void InsertEventIntoMagaya(EventType currentEvent)
{
    MagayaApi api = new MagayaApi();
    try
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(EventType));
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(result))
        {
            serializer.Serialize(writer, currentEvent);
            api.Cs.StartSession(api.User, api.Password, out int Key);
            api.Cs.SetTransactionEvents(Key, 0x00080000, "SH", "DUMMY999", result.ToString(), out string error);
            api.Cs.EndSession(Key);
        }
    }
    catch ( Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        throw;
    }
}
```

Also sample of the XML string as it should appear (with dummy data ofcourse):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Events xmlns = "http://www.magaya.com/XMLSchema/V1">
    <Event>
        <Date>2016-04-05T19:34:08+05:30</Date>
        <Details>Scanned</Details>
        <Location>Mumbai</Location>
        <EventDefinition>
            <Name>Cargo scanned in</Name>
            <IncludeInTracking>true</IncludeInTracking>
        </EventDefinition>
        <IncludeInTracking>true</IncludeInTracking>
        <OwnerType>SH</OwnerType>
        <OwnerNumber>162-78958749</OwnerNumber>
    <OwnerGUID>da3782e1-824b-4824-8ec2-0d38b032ab19</OwnerGUID>
    </Event>                                             
</Events>
```

The class that provides the C# field definitions and XML attributes:

```cs
/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.6.1055.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace = "http://www.magaya.com/XMLSchema/V1")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute("Events", Namespace = "http://www.magaya.com/XMLSchema/V1", IsNullable = false)]
public partial class EventList
{
    private EventType[] eventField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Event")]
    public EventType[] Event
    {
        get
        {
            return this.eventField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.eventField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.6.1055.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace = "http://www.magaya.com/XMLSchema/V1")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute("Event", Namespace = "http://www.magaya.com/XMLSchema/V1", IsNullable = false)]
public partial class EventType
{
    private System.DateTime dateField;
    private string detailsField;
    private string locationField;
    private EventDefinitionType eventDefinitionField;
    private bool includeInTrackingField;
    private bool includeInTrackingFieldSpecified;
    private string ownerTypeField;
    private string ownerGUIDField;
    private string ownerNumberField;
    private string ownerURLField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public System.DateTime Date
    {
        get
        {
            return this.dateField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.dateField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string Details
    {
        get
        {
            return this.detailsField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.detailsField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string Location
    {
        get
        {
            return this.locationField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.locationField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public EventDefinitionType EventDefinition
    {
        get
        {
            return this.eventDefinitionField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.eventDefinitionField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public bool IncludeInTracking
    {
        get
        {
            return this.includeInTrackingField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.includeInTrackingField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    public bool IncludeInTrackingSpecified
    {
        get
        {
            return this.includeInTrackingFieldSpecified;
        }
        set
        {
        this.includeInTrackingFieldSpecified = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string OwnerType
    {
        get
        {
            return this.ownerTypeField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.ownerTypeField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string OwnerGUID
    {
        get
        {
            return this.ownerGUIDField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.ownerGUIDField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string OwnerNumber
    {
        get
        {
            return this.ownerNumberField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.ownerNumberField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string OwnerURL
    {
        get
        {
            return this.ownerURLField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.ownerURLField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.6.1055.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace = "http://www.magaya.com/XMLSchema/V1")]
public partial class EventDefinitionType
{
    private string nameField;
    private string locationField;
    private string detailsField;
    private bool includeInTrackingField;
    private bool includeInTrackingFieldSpecified;

    /// <remarks/>
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return this.nameField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.nameField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string Location
    {
        get
        {
            return this.locationField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.locationField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string Details
    {
        get
        {
            return this.detailsField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.detailsField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public bool IncludeInTracking
    {
        get
        {
            return this.includeInTrackingField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.includeInTrackingField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    public bool IncludeInTrackingSpecified
    {
        get
        {
            return this.includeInTrackingFieldSpecified;
        }
        set
        {
            this.includeInTrackingFieldSpecified = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You get no result (a crash ?) or a wrong result ? The definition of serialization is all hidden in your classes like Events, Event, EventDefinition, etc.

Comment: It is malformed, and in the debugger I can see the String is missing a bunch of elements. If i dont stop the debugger, the method call causes an crash stating there is an error in the XML 1,40. Here is the class that generates the serialization attributes, my apologies:

Comment: Just edited main post and dropped the class in there. Hope that is enough... if not I will post the full code.

Comment: The definition corresponds to your expected output. If you cannot name at least one missing element, I can't help. The serializer.Serialize call is doing the formatting. Everything after is not related to serialization.

Comment: You don't close the `XmlWriter` before accessing `result`, so its buffers may not be flushed.  Move `result.ToString()` out of the `using` and see if the problem goes away.

Comment: Hi Holger, Maybe I misunderstood you. Let me try again, when I finish the serialization I am not seeing a list like structure of Events/Event, instead its just Event .

Comment: Also, that XML corresponds to an object of type `EventList` not `EventType`.

Comment: @dbc, no the EventList is correctly renamed with the XmlRootAttribute. But your guess with closing the writer might be good.

Comment: But beyond that I don't see a problem.  Deserializing the XML in your question to an `EventList` then serializing it back again works, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/KxUqt6.  Maybe you can clarify your problem with an [mcve]?

Comment: @Holger - in the code shown, OP is using a `new XmlSerializer(typeof(EventType));` but the XML shown has `<Events ... >` for the root node, so `new XmlSerializer(typeof(EventList))` should be used instead.  Trying to deserialize that XML with an `EventType` serializer fails, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/GdhMNQ